# Regex different results

Tags: javascript, regex

why do regex has different result between

[image]

basically if we look at the variable regex it is the same sa what is written in the console. but the results are different.

expected result should be

```
new RegExp('^(?!\\s*$)[A-Za-z0-9\\s.,-]*$', 'g').test(' 1');
true
```

Update

I see the difference, but how can you pass the regex value with out escaping the backslash

[image]

Eventually...
the JSON data was causing the HTML breaking not the expression, i thought '\' broke the HTML which i added '\' and fixed the JSON data but broke the results when trying to evaluate the value.

I had to fix the JSON data to parse '\' and now REGEXP is back to normal.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass"? Pass from where?

Comment: pass from $(control).data('regexvalidation')

Comment: But what is `control`? Is there user input involved, or... where is the regex coming from? Why not just hard-code it?

Comment: it is bound to a control as a data object coming from a configuration file.

Comment: Then change the configuration file?

Comment: Why not just instantiate it using `new RegExp`? `new RegExp('^(?!\\s*$)[A-Za-z0-9\\s.,-]*$', 'g')` evaluates the regex to `/^(?!\s*$)[A-Za-z0-9\s.,-]*$/g` which is what you're after, right?

Comment: @Jan Because OP isn't using a string literal, thus `\\ ` actually means `\\ `, and not `\ ` in the final regex.

Comment: No they aren't. I feel like I'm eating crazy pills http://jsbin.com/yoxukuvexu/edit?js,console It does exactly what OP wants unless I've misinterpreted what OP wants.

Comment: ok, i was too crazy trying to escape the backslash, i didn't notice that the json data was breaking and not the HTML which caused me to do the escaping. this is somehow fixed. sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: @Jan I said **no string literal**. [It does not work](https://jsfiddle.net/y26b8Lko/).

Comment: @Jan (quote) `it is bound to a control as a data object coming from a configuration file.`

Comment: @Siguza , your original comment said *nothing about string literals*. Changing your entire comment like that after someone's already replied makes following the conversation pretty confusing. And yeah Juvil, if you need to escape it for posting through JSON, then you should do only just that.

Answer (score 1):

Because `new RegExp('\\') != /\\/`, it is equal to `/\/`.
Replacing `\\` by `\` in the literal regex makes it work:

```
/^(?!\s*$)[A-Za-z0-9\s.,-]*$/g.test(' 1');
// => true
```

Comment: i stored the expression from $(control), so it needs to escape the backlash, now i see the difference, but how can you remove the escaped backslash before instantiating the regexp object.

Answer (score 1):

In your second construction, `regexp = /^(?!\\s*$)[A-Za-z0-9\\s.,-]*$/g`, you don't need to escape the backslashes. Since you did, it thinks you're looking for a literal backslash followed by the letter `s`.

Try this: `regexp = /^(?!\s*$)[A-Za-z0-9\s.,-]*$/g`